# vtiger crm installatin process in window 7 using wamp server

Tags: vtiger

I'm a php web developer.
Please talk me full process for vtiger crm installatin in window 7 using wamp server

I have unzip vtigercrm6.2.0.tar.gz in c:/wamp /www  folder and then run it generates more errors
show errors please click on bellow link

→http://awesomescreenshot.com/0844m9zi18

Answer (score 0):

What's your PHP-Version of your wamp-installation?

http://community.vtiger.com/help/vtigercrm/administrators/installation.html#pre-requisites

VTiger requires

> PHP 5.2+, 5.3